# After creating textfile i see that file is not there in the given path.where is it stored in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I wrote the below piece of code where i am creating a text file in a particular path,then when i check in the path , i do not see any text file created.Where is the file stored?

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f1 = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", True)
f1.WriteLine "Hello World"
f1.Close

Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", 1)
s = ts.ReadLine
print s
ts.Close
```

But i dont see the text file in the path "c:\testfile.txt"
Please reply if anyone knows the reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it throw any error? I do not see any issues with the script. Your script works fine in my UFT.

Comment: when i tried with different path in c drive,it worked fine...TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid `print` is not a valid VBScript command; use

```
wscript.echo s
```

However, writing to a disk root: `c:\testfile.txt` leads to an `access denied` error; try `c:\somepath\testfile.txt`

Comment: print is an inbuilt function in hp-uft, so it is valid

Comment: yes...you are write when i tried with c:\somepath\testfile.txt ..it worked fine. TY

Comment: @user90 How cool would it be if you accepted this answer, it would be the second time (after having posted lots of questions, all without an accepted answer after years).